# Django forms is_valid() for registration, always false

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, django-forms

I'm still learning django and I'm trying to create a register and login page.
I beleive i created the form right, and the .is_valid() looks good to me also, I have no idea what i did wrong.

every time I submit the register form, it fails and renders the else condition, same with the login function, even thought I went into admin to add a user manually.

my user model is called 'Users'
Forms:

```
class reg_form(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=64)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="email", max_length=64)
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Phone', max_length=64)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=64)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=64)

class log_form(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=64)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Register:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = reg_form(request.POST)
        
        
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user = Users.objects.Create(username=username, email=email, password=password, phone=phone, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
            Users.save(user)
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'profile.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'register.html', {
            'form': reg_form 
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html', {
            'form': reg_form
        })
```

login:

```
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = log_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'profile.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html', {
                    'form2': log_form
                })
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {
            'form2': log_form
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {
            'form2': log_form
        })
```

Comment: You should return a Bound Form to see the errors: `if form.is_valid():... else return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form })` and the same for login.

Comment: @NKSM I believe i am returning a form {'form': reg_form}, or is this not correct?

Comment: I believe using a `ModelForm` instead of a `Form` will make sure your validation is correct. Maybe it's your password that can't be validated. Just extend the default `User` model and add the fields you need such as the phone number and the email. [Model Form Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: @beatmaister, you have to return: `render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form })`

Comment: @beatmaister, `create()` method for creating an object and saving it all in one step. See [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create). After that, you don't need to call the `save()` method.

Comment: @FrédéricPerron I tried using modelForms instead and i am getting the exact same issue, and still no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the errors you should return [Bound Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms):

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = reg_form(request.POST)
   
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get'email')
            phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user = Users.objects.create(
                username=username, email=email,
                password=password, phone=phone,
                first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name
            )
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'profile.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'register.html', {
            # If the form not valid return bound form
            'form': form 
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html', {
            'form': reg_form
        })
```

And do the same in your **`log_in`** view.

---

I suggest you to use **[ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)**.

Also see [**Coding style**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#coding-style) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#coding-style)):

- Use **InitialCaps** for class names (or for factory functions that return
  classes).
- Field names should be all **lowercase**, using underscores instead of
  camelCase.

Comment: this unfortunately solved nothing, the exact same issue is happening. I tries using modelForms also and no go.

Comment: @beatmaister, after submitting which page is rendered?

Comment: the register form still loads in on the register.html page. even using modelForms

Comment: @beatmaister, Could you print in console `form.errors`?

Comment: do i do that by adding a print statement to the view function? because i did that and, it does not print anything to the console when it fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232366/discussion-between-nksm-and-beatmaister).